# SNOPT Exception when adding collisions to a trajectory optimization problem

Tags: drake

I am working on a trajectory optimization problem for a ball to get from point A to point B on a plane. Direct collocation was working fine before I added obstacles. However, when I added obstacle links and collision tags to my URDF model (without changing the direct collocation code), I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Exception while evaluating SNOPT costs and constraints: 'You've tried evaluating time derivatives or their residuals.

The provided context doesn't show a connection for the plant's query input port (see MultibodyPlant::get_geometry_query_input_port()). See https://drake.mit.edu/troubleshooting.html#mbp-unconnected-query-object-port for help.'
```

What does this error mean? I'm not sure what "time derivatives or their residuals" this would be referring to, which is making it hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got a chance to click on the [link](https://drake.mit.edu/troubleshooting.html#mbp-unconnected-query-object-port) in the error message? Please let us know if the explanation in that link is not clear.

It depends on how you construct DirectCollocation. I assume that you have a multibody plant, and you create a context for this multibody plant, then pass that plant and the context to DirectCollocation. Your code probably looks like this

```py
my_plant = CreateMyPlant(...)
plant_context = my_plant->CreateDefaultContext()
dir_col = DirectCollocation(my_plant, *plant_context, ...)
```

This code works fine when you do not have collision geometry. When you have the collision geometry, now to evaluate the dynamics with the collision, it needs another component, namely the SceneGraph, and the context need to show a connection between the plant query input port to SceneGraph.

To build that connection between the plant query input port and the SceneGraph, you can do this

```py
builder = DiagramBuilder()
# Build plant and scene graph and automatically connect them.
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(
       builder=builder, time_step=0)
   ...
diagram = builder.Build()

diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
# Extract the plant's context from the diagram's to invoke plant methods.
plant_context = plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context=diagram_context)

dir_col = DirectCollocation(plant, plant_context, ...)
```

Now this `plant_context` is extracted from the `diagram_context`. This diagram contains both the plant and the scene_graph, and the plant is property connected to the scene_graph.